# Nativescript error for faker: cannot find module './address'

Tags: typescript, nativescript, faker

I am learning nativescript. I am trying to use faker to create some data with typescript.

Node version - 6.9.4
Faker - 3.1.0
typescript - 2.1.4

I got this error and haven't been able to run the app.

> 1   0x103841709 NativeScript::FFICallback::ffiClosureCallback(ffi_cif*, void*, void**, void*)
>       2   0x103eac01e ffi_closure_unix64_inner
>       3   0x103eac9d2 ffi_closure_unix64
>       4   0x104a92cd3 -[UIViewController view]
>       5   0x104968fb4 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible]
>       6   0x10496969d -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:]
>       7   0x10497b180 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible]
>       8   0x103eac82d ffi_call_unix64
>       9   0x117f966d0
>   file:///app/tns_modules/Faker/lib/locales/ja/index.js:4:21: JS ERROR Error: Could not find module './address'. Computed path '/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CB21F7AD-A7B5-4D7D-96E2-218F3EDAEA1B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E503DADB-A0F5-49E6-A65B-A2F2072DB885/demo1.app/app/tns_modules/Faker/lib/locales/ja/address'.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the library with a new NativeScript project and it works as expected.
Here is what I have done, step by step:

```
npm i Faker --save
```

And afterwards:

```
var faker = require('Faker'); 
var randomName = faker.Name.findName();

export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {
    console.log("randomName: " + randomName); // returns random name like Carmela Weimann
}
```

Sample application [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/tree/master/stackoverflow/fakerUsageTest)